# System call in JRuby as an administrator

Tags: ruby, windows, command-line, jruby

I'm sending a command to the command prompt (in JRuby script) with:

```
system("cd .. && REG ADD \"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\etc\\foo\\foo\" /f /v Data /t REG_SZ /d 3")
```

However, I need administrative rights to execute that command. If I have administrative rights on my machine, how can I tell the command prompt that through this system call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well have you tried doing a "sudo" with **runas** e.g. `runas /noprofile /user:Administrator`

```
system("runas /noprofile /user:Administrator REG ADD \"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\etc\\foo\\foo\" /f /v Data /t REG_SZ /d 3")
```

for more please see https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows